# Please welcome your new Moderators!

Tags: discussion, moderation

Moderators, check your email! Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community in both community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here:

[**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image]

[image]

[image]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

### Did I overlook anyone?

**Almost certainly**. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why we eventually hold elections.

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Answer (score 12):

Thanks for appointing me as a mod!

I see that there are some historical mod flags here on the meta site. I'll make sure to stay familiar with what's going on over here as we go forward, so that I can better deal with such issues in future.

There don't seem to be any flags over on the main site, though. So that seems like a good sign so far!

Answer (score 11):

I'd like to say thank you for the mod appointment, as James Wootton said.

To anyone who has questions, comments, or concerns: feel free to post on meta or ping me in a chatroom (preferably The Classical Channel, but the hbar works as well). I look forward to helping this site!

To both of the other mods: congrats, and I look forward to working with you!